# A template for my buttons - C#, Razor, MVC 5.0

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

Sure, I've given them a class and I can style them all just from that css class.. but god forbid I ever need to change the html of them...

I have 4 buttons:

```
Create/Edit/Delete/View
```

currently they are like so:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning">Edit</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">View</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
```

I think I would like to have 4 template files or even 8 that includes the 4/8 different html elements... then use a function to call upon them instead in my Razor view... What's the usual approach for this?

I was using @Html.ActionLink etc... but I don't want to set a default template for that because it needs to be what it is... but maybe something like **@Html.PostButton / @Html.ActionButton**

The PostButton would literally be the `<button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>`
 and the ActionButton would be the template like this:

```
<a href="Something/Create"><button class="btn btn-primary">Create</button></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you want, still I can suggest you following

**Use PartialViews**

you can create partialViews for your custom buttons and use them, so that whenever you have to change something, you can change that in one location and it will reflect everywhere else i.e.

```
@Html.Partial("_PrimaryButton")
@{ Html.RenderPartial("_AlertButton");  }
```

**Use HtmlHelpers**

(Recommended).You can actually add your custom extension to the `@Html`  i.e. something like `@Html.MyPrimaryButton("Name","OnClickEvent","Anything")`

creating an HtmlHelper extension is exactly similar to any typical c# extension i.e.

1. Create a Static Class
2. Add a Static Method to it and Make its first argument the class you want to extend (in this case HtmlHelper) prefixed by `this`
3. Make sure you include the namespace in the view, you wish to use the Extension i.e

   ```
   @using MyNamespace;
   ```

so a typical example can be:

```
public static class MyExtensions
{

    public static string MyButton(this HtmlHelper helper, string name, 
                              string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        return @"<a href='/" + controllerName + "/" + actionName +
                 "' class='btn' >" +  name + "</a>";
    }     
}
```

read more about MVC Custom Html Helpers [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)

Comment: Naming convention question: I see that it mentions the folder - Helpers\LabelHelper.cs, is that from the root of your MVC Project or is it typical to find it within Models? or ViewHelpers?

Comment: you can keep it anywhere, doesn't matter, all that matters is you have included the namespace in the view(no matter what it is).

Comment: moreover, you can declare your HtmlHelpers on Views itself

Comment: Is there any benefit to using the TagBuilder class? Or is that for people who don't understand html and css? eg: 
            TagBuilder anchorTag = new TagBuilder("a");
            anchorTag.AddCssClass("btn");